# Can't toggle checkboxes created dynamically

Tags: php, html

I hope you are doing well.
I'm trying to generate dynamically checkboxes (with foreach and such), the problem is when I add the id field like here:

```
<input class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" name="state[]" id="state" <?php echo ($option->option_on > 0 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> value="<?php echo $option->option_ref; ?>"/>
```

And when I toggle one of the checkboxes, it changes only the first one's state.

But when I remove it, the checkboxes doesn't work anymore.

Thank you for your interest.
Have a good day.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be UNIQUE on a page. If you are in a loop then it wont be unique unless you make it so by adding something to the simple `id="state"`

Comment: If you show us the `foreach()` code then maybe we can be more helpful

Comment: Just noticed that when I change the id it stops working ...

Answer (score 1):

Every element in DOM must have a unique id.
You must change id of it,

```
$ref = $option->option_ref;
$opt = $option->option_on;
echo "<input class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' type='checkbox'  
name='state[]' id='state$ref'" .($opt > 0 ? "checked='checked'" : "").  
"value='$ref'/>";
```

should work.

Comment: Changed my snippet completely. Once try to replace your code with mine and check.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution I'll post it in case ... (it's hilarious btw).
It had to do with the checkboxe's label: The value of the "for" field in label should be the same as the checkboxe's id ... if it's not it doesn't work and if you have multiple checkboxes and they all have the same id (and thus the same value of the "for" field in label), when you try to check/uncheck one it'll change the first one's state.
Hope it's clear and it'll be helpful for someone one day ...
Thank you so much.